# Sum of outputs of same rank in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How can we do summation when rnk = 1 ?

**My output**

```
1 A. 40. 01/02/2023

1 A. 60. 04/02/2023
```

**Desired output**

```
1 A. 100. 01/02/2023
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use combination of subqueries and aggregations

```
 SELECT
      rnk,
      category,
      SUM(value) AS total_value,
      date
    FROM (
      SELECT
        rnk,
        category,
        value,
        date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rnk, category, date ORDER BY date) AS row_number
      FROM
        your_table
    ) subquery
    WHERE
      row_number = 1
    GROUP BY
      rnk,
      category,
      date
```

Comment: Hello, this gave me the same results